# extract data from file through regex

Tags: python, regex

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
```

All I want is to convert the above data  into a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary looks like the following:

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

kindly help me i am new!!

Comment: What is the question?   “kindly help me i am new!!”  Kindly provide a question with specific debugging details.

Comment: Do some research on regex matching groups.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^
(?P<host>\d+\S+)[-\s]+
(?P<user_name>\S+)\s+
\[(?P<time>[^][]+)\]\s+
"(?P<request>[^"]+)"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0YAgdv/1).

---

In `Python` this could be

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"""
    ^
    (?P<host>\d+\S+)[-\s]+
    (?P<user_name>\S+)\s+
    \[(?P<time>[^][]+)\]\s+
    "(?P<request>[^"]+)"
""", re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

data = """
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701
100.32.205.59 - ortiz8891 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700] "PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0" 204 6048
"""

for match in pattern.finditer(data):
    dct = match.groupdict()
    print(dct)
```

And would yield

```
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}
{'host': '156.127.178.177', 'user_name': 'okuneva5222', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700', 'request': 'DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1'}
{'host': '100.32.205.59', 'user_name': 'ortiz8891', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700', 'request': 'PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code i'm using re to search patterns, then gathering matches in the dictionary unit_d. List fulllist contains all dictionaries.

```
import re
filename='c:/test/log.txt'
fulllist=[]
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        unit_d=dict()
        text=line.rstrip()
        finder=re.search('([\d\.]+)[\s-]+(\w+) \[([\w/: -]+)\] "([^"]+)',text)
        unit_d['host']=finder.group(1)
        unit_d['user_name']=finder.group(2)
        unit_d['time']=finder.group(3)
        unit_d['request']=finder.group(4)
        print unit_d
        fulllist.append(unit_d)
```

results

```
{'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1', 'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700'}
{'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0', 'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700'}
{'request': 'DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1', 'host': '156.127.178.177', 'user_name': 'okuneva5222', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700'}
{'request': 'PATCH /architectures HTTP/1.0', 'host': '100.32.205.59', 'user_name': 'ortiz8891', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:28 -0700'}
```

Comment: thanks changed this to one regex string pattern with groups. But your code with named groups and match.groupdict() is more beautiful @Jan